# Limiting SQL Search When a Value is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add another statement to the WHERE clause of this SQL query to throw out some entries I do not need.

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, CreateTimestamp) Year
, DATEPART(Month, CreateTimestamp) Month
, COUNT(*) Accepted

FROM Interactions t

WHERE t.QueueName = @queuName 
    AND (CAST(CreateTimestamp AS DATE) BETWEEN @firstMonth AND @lastMonth)
    AND TransferFrom != 'Yes'
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, CreateTimestamp), DATEPART(Month, CreateTimestamp)
```

I need to add the filter `DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateTimestamp, AbandonTimestamp) > 10` , but only if `AbandonTimestamp` is not NULL. I know that there is a `ISNULL()` function, but I basicly need the exact opposite of that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the where statement, you have "WHERE t.QueueName = @queuName". Is @queuName the correct variable name (missing an e)?

Comment: @Dan that's the correct variable, its just a spelling error on my part, thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AbandonTimestamp` is null, the date calculation result will be null, so just use `COALESCE()` to provide a passing value in this case:

```
WHERE COALESCE(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateTimestamp,
       AbandonTimestamp), 11) > 10
```

To explain in more detail, the `COALESCE()` function returns the first term in its list of parameters that is not null. For example:

- `coalesce(1, 2, 3)` -> 1
- `coalesce(null, 2, 3)` -> 2
- `coalesce(null, null)` -> null

In the expression above, there are only two parameters - the two queries.
Now if there are no rows in the first table, the result if `max()` will be null, so coalesce will return the result of the second query (which could also be null if there are no rows in it either).

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/334) of the whole expression.

Comment: The COALESCE worked perfectly, although I'm not really sure what the 11 at the end of the function for, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @trumpet7347 FYI I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ISNULL and use CreateTimestamp when AbandonTimestamp is NULL.  This will result in DATEDIFF being false, since the number of elapsed seconds would be 0.

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, CreateTimestamp) Year
, DATEPART(Month, CreateTimestamp) Month
, COUNT(*) Accepted
FROM Interactions t
WHERE t.QueueName = @queuName 
AND (CAST(CreateTimestamp AS DATE) BETWEEN @firstMonth AND @lastMonth)
AND TransferFrom != 'Yes'
AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateTimestamp, ISNULL(AbandonTimestamp, CreateTimestamp)) > 10
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, CreateTimestamp), DATEPART(Month, CreateTimestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement. Note this condition is inclusive if null.

`And 10 < Case When AbandonTimestamp Then 9 Else DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateTimestamp, AbandonTimestamp) End`

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you're going for. It adds a check if AbandonTimestamp is NULL, then that's okay. If it's not null, then you need the datediff between CurrentTimestamp and AbandonTimestamp to be less than 10.

```
WHERE t.QueueName = @queuName 
    AND (CAST(CreateTimestamp AS DATE) BETWEEN @firstMonth AND @lastMonth)
    AND TransferFrom != 'Yes'
    AND (
          (AbandonTimestamp IS NULL)
          OR (AbandonTimestamp IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateTimestamp, AbandonTimestamp) > 10)
         )
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, CreateTimestamp), DATEPART(Month, CreateTimestamp)
```

Comment: Agree this will work, but from previous testing ISNULL or COALESCE seems to give better performance for complex queries instead of OR

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up Greg. An answer like JackAce or Bohemians is probably better then.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, CreateTimestamp) Year
, DATEPART(Month, CreateTimestamp) Month
, COUNT(*) Accepted

FROM Interactions t

WHERE t.QueueName = @queuName 
    AND (CAST(CreateTimestamp AS DATE) BETWEEN @firstMonth AND @lastMonth)
    AND TransferFrom != 'Yes'
    AND (AbandonTimestamp IS NULL 
         OR AbandonTimestamp > DATEADD(second, 10, CreateTimestamp)) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, CreateTimestamp), DATEPART(Month, CreateTimestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can append this statement

( AbandonTimestamp is not null and  DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateTimestamp, AbandonTimestamp) > 10)